# Why does my App.Config codebase not help .NET locate my assembly?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, codebase

I have the following client application and its corresponding `config` file:

```
namespace Chapter9
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ExecuteAssembly("AssemblyPrivate.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <codeBase href="file://C:\Users\djpiter\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\70536\AssemblyPrivate\bin\Debug\AssemblyPrivate.exe"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

The `AssemblyPrivate.exe` does not have a public key, nor is it located in the GAC. As far as I know, the runtime should parse the `app.config` file before looking for an assembly in the client app directory.

The unhandled exception (wrapped for readability) is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///C:\Users\djpiter\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\70536\Chapter9\bin\Debug\AssemblyPrivate.exe'
> or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Why it is not working? I need to use dynamic binding (not static).

Comment: What is the relationship between the path of the main exe and the assembly (is it in a sub folder)?

Comment: Yes. It is located in subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't overlook that "*or one of its dependencies*". Are you sure all AssemblyPrivate.exe's dependencies are available?

Comment: AssemblyPrivate is just a static void main with Console.WriteLine so - Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Have you tried using the full path as an argument to the ExecuteAssembly method? In the standard Windows form, not as URL?

Comment: I know, but if you want to find out where the problem lies, you have to do a little bit of experimenting... that's always the case with these kinds of things

Answer (score 0):

You probably solved this problem on your own by now, so just for reference:

I believe you are missing an "assemblyIdentity" element. If you specify it additionally to the codeBase element, it should work.

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="office"
                  publicKeyToken="71e9bce111e9429c" />
        <codeBase href="Microsoft.Office.Interop.v11.dll" version="11.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0yt6ck0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Q: "The `AssemblyPrivate.exe` does not have a public key", that's the problem.

Comment: If there is no public key, just leave out the whole `publicKeyToken` element. Worked for me.